# Wifi Card Removed, computer still shows data packets sent/received

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have purposely removed the wifi card on my macbook in order to work offline securely. The "Activity Monitor" still shows packets are being sent/received. How is this possible?

Of particular interest are processes "syslogd" and "discoveryd"

Comment: Could be local processes that are try to connect to a destination. To get a better understanding it's recommended to run Wireshark, this should give you some insight in the (internal) network flow.

Answer (score 3):

Processes can communicate on TCP/IP between themselves locally, and that is especially true in Linux/Unix systems. You can use `netstat` and `tcpdump`to figure out what's happening.

`netstat -s` will show you statistics of internal processes but is very verbose. A nice way to see what's changing in to run `watch netstat -s`. Too bad `watch` is not included in OSX, so you have to install it, `brew install watch`.